# Shared Cloud Storage for Teams with option to upload only and no download

Tags: file-sharing, cloud-storage, internet-security, system-administration

I am looking for a shared cloud storage for teams. Ideally the admin can assign what directories the members can see. And the members can only upload files and see the contents in the directory but they cannot download and delete. I have tried dropbox for teams but it cannot. Also preferably not google drive. Thank you!

Comment: Requests for product recommendations are off topic here. Please read the Help section.

Comment: For questions about [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) you'd use the link and delete your question here on SuperUser.